# Android, sending and recieving info from server

Tags: android

I'm working on an android app that has to send and receive information from a 3rd party server.  I'm not experienced at this at all, so bear with me if I give too much/too little/not the right kind of information at first.

The API that was provided to send information has the format

```
https://methodurl.com/username=user&password=pass&key=key&info=infotosend
```

When I put this URL into my desktops browser, it returns a string, which I'm also trying to get.  At least, I'm assuming all it returns is a string, since if I look at the page source, there is just a string, such as "200 OK" or "401 Unauthorized".

The code I'm using is what I can glean from the web what I'm supposed to use.  Unfortunately, for all I know, I'm writing code to do something very different than what I want.  I've never written code to interact with a server before, so this is all new to me.

Here's my code:

```
TextView urlView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.url_view);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(siteToSubmit);
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    try {
        String serverResponse = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
        urlView.setText(serverResponse);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Logcat in eclipse (when app is running on the emulator) is

```
java.net.UnknownHostException
```

The way I understand the code to be working is I'm creating a client that will execute on a url (like would happen when I hit enter in the URL bar on a browser), a request for that client to execute on, and a handler to receive the response from the server, which is set to be recieved as a string.  I am then trying to set that string as the text in a TextView to verify that I am getting the proper response.  Right now, I just get the log error, and urlView does not change.  Any ideas why?  Am I understanding the process correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the uses-permission `android.permission.INTERNET`?

Comment: Well, I feel dumb.  Nope, I didn't add the permission.  This is also my first android app.  Thanks!  Can't seem to select your answer though, not sure why.  Worked perfectly once I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the uses-permission `android.permission.INTERNET` to the manifest file.